# How to draw quarter circle curves in python

Tags: python, matlab, canvas, tkinter, graphing

I want to draw this 4-petal unit in red for my program:

[image]

I need to be able to draw every curve separately, so that I can bold them to make the bold white patterns show in the pic.

I was thinking about placing my origin coordinate in the center, and drawing 8 quarter circles around the dot.

[image]

Hopefully I would only have 1 function, a quarter circle, and could repeat that one (eg. mirror it over the y axis) to make all 8.

However, I could not do it with Tkinter or matlab.

With Tkinter I can only draw one arc (with extra lines) at a time.

Tkinter code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bg='black')
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_arc(100, 100, 200, 200, start=0, extent=90, outline="white",style="pieslice")

root.mainloop()
```

Using Matlab I can only make 'quarter circles' by literally minimizing the graph size so it only shows the window I want:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
xlist = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 100) # only in quadrant I
ylist = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
F = X**2 + Y**2 - 1  #  'Circle Equation
plt.contour(X, Y, F, [0], colors = 'k', linestyles = 'solid')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i did it,
use style = "arc" instead of pieslice and draw 4 half circles

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bg='black')
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_arc(100, 0, 200, 100, start=0, extent=-180, outline="white", style="arc")
canvas.create_arc(100, 100, 200, 200, start=0, extent=180, outline="white", style="arc")
canvas.create_arc(150, 50, 250, 150, start=90, extent=180, outline="white", style="arc")
canvas.create_arc(50, 50, 150, 150, start=90, extent=-180, outline="white", style="arc")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are showing is in basic is 4 semi circles rotated 90 degrees clockwise.
You can draw a semi circle by setting a limit for the equation x^2 + y^2 - 1 such that it produces a semi circle.